# Facebook PHP SDK Extracting Access Token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Every time I run this script it gives me a different access token.  I thought the access token was unique to a user..  Also why is this script so unreliable, fails half the time.

[My Facebook Access Token Page](http://www.storeboard.com/facebook/gettoken.php)

Here is the code:

```
<?php
require 'lib/facebook.php';
require_once('C:\inetpub\storeboard.com\linkedin\extract_data.php');

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => FACEBOOK_APPID,
  'secret' => FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
    $user = null;
  }
}

$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
if (isset($access_token)) {
   echo $access_token;
    //header( 'Location: http://www.'.APP_ROOT_DOMAIN.'/facebook/save_token.asp?nToken='.$access_token);
}

?>
```

Have I cut out code that is required from the original: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/534/
or am I missing something.

```
require_once('C:\inetpub\storeboard.com\linkedin\extract_data.php');
```

This line of code just extracts the APPID and APPSECRET from the database.

I am a complete beginner when it comes to PHP, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks!

Comment: user access tokens have an expiry of about 2 hours, calling will not always get you a new token, but if it is expired you will get a new token.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to play with the token to get simple authentication:

After you get facebook api instance:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => FACEBOOK_APPID,
  'secret' => FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET
));
```

If you are using me API - get the user profile:

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
```

then obtain email from it:

```
$email = $user_profile['email'];
```

At this point you check if the email is valid in your database - if yes start the user session and you are good to go.